# Django & Celery: Do I need transaction.atomic/locking in order to avoid race-conditions?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, atomic

Users in my app can import data fetched from an API into my Django database. The API uses paging if there are > 100 results to fetch.

I obviously don't want the users to wait to for a possibly big number of items to import. So I'm doing the first call to the API in the request, and then delegating the rest to Celery.

```
> User requests an API item with 250 items
> Fetch 100 and return
> Fetch 150 more in a celery task
```

I'm worried about database corruption. I'm running my app on Heroku.

I call the task like so:

```py
if rginitial_count >= 100:
     continue_doing_imports.delay(artist_mbid=self.mbid,
                                  artist_name=self.name,
                                  offset=100)
```

How can I ensure consistent behavior? for example, `user A` is importing data for `Artist X`, and at the same time `user B` attempts to subscribe to that same artist, therefore needing to write to his relationships? that's one scenario I can think of.